# Navigating from one page to Another page in spring webflow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

can anyone give a simple example for spring webflow to navigate from one page to another page using a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to be more a little more specific. but if you just want to navigate from one page to another, in terms of Webflow you can do this in the same flow:

these 2 pages will be 2 `view-state` and by clicking on a button you want to trigger an event that will transition you to from one to the other.

```
<view-state id="viewState1" view="viewPage1.html">
    <transition on="nextPage" to="viewState2"/>
</view-state>

<view-state id="viewState2" view="viewPage2.html">
    <transition on="previousPage" to="viewState1"/>
</view-state>
```

in your web page, you just need a submit button like this:
page 1:

```
<input type="submit" name="_eventId_nextPage" value="Next Page"/>
```

page 2:

```
<input type="submit" name="_eventId_previousPage" value="Previous Page"/>
```

I strongly advice you to read the documentation and some tutorials as there are many ways to accomplish this